# how to convert add another level to nested dictionary which has a tuple as a key in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, tuples

There is a nested dictionary whose second level key is in tuples such as:

```
dic1={'a': {('a', 'b'): ['c','d'],
    ('a', 'c'): ['d','f','g'],
    ('c', 'k'): ['f','h'],
    ('c', 'j'): [], 
    ('h', 'z'): ['w']
}}
```

I would like to convert the tuple keys at the second level into other level of key so that the nested dictionary looks like as

```
{
    'a':
    {
        'a':
        {
            'b': ['c', 'd'],
            'c': ['d', 'f', 'g']
        },
        'c':
        {
            'k': ['f', 'h'],
            'j': []
        },
        'h':
        {
            'z': ['w']
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the code below but I cannot get the expected result

```
dic2 = {k:[i[0] for i in v] for k,v in dic1.items()}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recursion suit for this problem

Comment: @Mark you're right, it is. I just re-formatted it so it's more clear.

Comment: If one key is `('a', 'b')` and another is `('a', 'b', 'c')`, what is the answer?

Comment: @MechanicPig, the tuple will always have 2 inputs so it wont be `('a', 'b', 'c')` for my data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After observing the problem description, it seems that the structure of the data provided by OP is very fixed (and more general recursive structure have many limitations, because it is necessary to avoid that the deepest value is both a dictionary and a list), so the recursive scheme is abandoned here and the loop is hard coded:

```
def make_nested(mp):
    res = {}
    for k, v in mp.items():
        res[k] = new_val = {}
        for (vk1, vk2), vv in v.items():
            new_val.setdefault(vk1, {})[vk2] = vv
    return res
```

Test:

```
>>> mapping
{'a': {('a', 'b'): ['c', 'd'],
       ('a', 'c'): ['d', 'f', 'g'],
       ('c', 'k'): ['f', 'h'],
       ('c', 'j'): [],
       ('h', 'z'): ['w']}}
>>> make_nested(mapping)
{'a': {'a': {'b': ['c', 'd'], 'c': ['d', 'f', 'g']},
       'c': {'k': ['f', 'h'], 'j': []},
       'h': {'z': ['w']}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
big_dic = {}
for k, v in dic1.items():
    big_dic[k] = {}
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        big_dic[k][k1[0]] = {}
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        big_dic[k][k1[0]][k1[1]] = v1
```